# Bash output of sysvinit process unable to store to variable if process not running

Tags: bash

I ran into a problem which makes no sense to me.

I have a sysvinit script which I use to get the status of a Process.

Its called like that:
`/etc/init.d/process status`

It gives this output when the process is running:
`Checking for service process                                                                                                                                                                      running`

and this if it is dead for example:
`Checking for service process                                                                                                                                                                      dead`

I want to use the status of this output in a bash script like so:

`status=$(/etc/init.d/process status | cut -d ' ' -f 5)`

so the Process is running, I Issue the command:

```
SERVER:~ # status=$(/etc/init.d/process status | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
SERVER:~ # echo $status
..running
```

thats the expected behaviour.
Now when I do the same when the Process is dead , I get a completely different behaviour:

```
SERVER:~ # status=$(/etc/init.d/process status | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
..dead
SERVER:~ # echo $status
```

As you can see, instead of writing the result to the status variable it just gets printed on stdout and is not written to the variable at all.
Can someone explain me, why this happens?

Comment: It's being written to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Things written to stderr are for humans, not scripts/software, to read. As a script, you should check the exit status, not the textual description; every distro I've written sysv init scripts for has a standard for what `$?` should be for each possible status.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed out on the error codes.
I did it like this now and it works perfectly:
`/etc/init.d/process status > /dev/null`
`PROCESS_STATUS=$?`

Comment: Glad to help! As an aside, think about using lowercase variables -- [POSIX standardizes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) that OS components use only all-caps names for things that change or reflect their behavior, reserving lowercase names for application use. Being in the habit of using lowercase names for everything that _isn't_ shell- or OS-defined means you never run `for PATH in /dir/*; do` and then find yourself wondering why you can't run any external commands. :)